# How to apply Deeplab V3 in Android studio for segmentation purpose?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, deeplab

Actually i am a beginner in Tensorflow and Deeplab V3. I literally don't know how to integrate deep lab on android studio. I only just want to use tensorflow trained example model for semantic segmentation in android not real time video image. I have seen a lots of github code but didn't able to run in my android phone.

1.https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/segmentation/overview

If the above code would run well on my phone then i would be able to train this for my data set but firstly i want to run the model on my phone how it's actually work. It would great help for me if someone exactly show me the right way because i have tried since form yesterday morning. so please ..

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dailystudio/ml/tree/master/deeplab. 
you can download a demo app here and start working. This app runs off the shelf, just download it from github and open in android studio

Comment: This demo when applied works too slow . Is it compatible accurately and well supported yet ?